# Read a serialport in real time

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to perform a control where I receive information sent by Arduino.

This information is of type string and format VX 1.987 or VY 0.123 and are sent at high speed. After they are filtered and treated, they update the textbox in my program, and in this way what I see in the TextBox is the last information received.

What happens with my code is that at a certain point, for example, were sent 1000 lines by the Arduino, my program will update up to 600 and then stop showing the updates. I know that in the receive buffer are the other 400 rows, but they were not shown.
Summarizing how do I make memo time be receiving the information by serial and reading and putting in the textbox? Could this be a processing time issue? How to solve?

```
namespace ControleCaseiro
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         serialPort1.DataReceived += new    SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
    } 

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                   
                    DataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(MostraDados));                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { }
        }

     private void MostraDados(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        switch (DataIn)
            {
                case "19\r":
                    textcontrole.Text = "XOFF";
                    break;
                case "17\r":
                     textcontrole.Text = "XON";
                    if (botãoEnviaGcode)
                    {
                        LinhaArquivo++;
                        EnviaGcode();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    FiltroDadosRecebidos(DataIn);                 
                    break;
            }      
      }

    private void FiltroDadosRecebidos(string valorRecebido)
     {        
        string eixo="";
        int tamanho=0;
        string valorEixoAtual="";
        if (valorRecebido.Length > 1)
            {               
                    tamanho = valorRecebido.Length;           
                     eixo = valorRecebido.Substring(0, 2);                   
            switch (eixo)
               {                             
                  case "VX":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);           
                              txtPosAtualX.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                  case "VY":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);
                              txtPosAtualY.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                  case "VZ":
                              valorEixoAtual = valorRecebido.Substring(2, tamanho - 3);
                              txtPosAtualZ.Text=valorEixoAtual;
                              break;
                   default :
                              DadosRecebidos.Items.Add(DataIn);// se não for dados referentes aos eixos, vai mostrar na listbox “DadosRecebidos”
                              break;
               }

            }                     

        }
    }
```

As I have already described in the beginning, what it is that the Arduino is sending the information and after a while, everything to and the information is not shown in the TextBox. What it looks like is that while OA SerialPort is receiving data, the event  "SerialDataReceivedEventArgs " causes the program to show the information, when it is out of receive, no longer shows and the information is accumulated in the serialport buffer.

Comment: Talking about "real time" is not sensible, your user's eyes are not close to being capable of reading text at a rate that a serial port can spit out.  This does go wrong, pretty quickly, at some point it takes the text box more time to repaint itself than it takes you to poke it with more data.  You *must* throw away old text.  Just keep in mind that this is not a useful UI feature for a high-speed serial port connection, you can't fix the user's eyes.  Focus on actually using the data instead of just dumping it into a textbox.  A typical getting-started problem.

Comment: That empty catch block is going to get you in trouble. At a minimum, at least log something. By catching the exception and simply throwing it away you are hindering your ability to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that you're not handling all the data in the receive buffer. You're only extracting one line of the receive buffer even though there may be multiple lines waiting to be processed. You could try changing your handler to something like this:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                DataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(MostraDados));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: I would also suggest not to Invoke it.   But instead read all the bytes in one go and put them in a thread safe queue for something else to handle.

Comment: @KeithNicholas it is a winform, I dont think there is any other option to prevent cross-threading on the UI

Comment: @bwing Thanks for the info on  "BytesToRead ". It worked perfectly.

Comment: @leppie  what I meant is the Invoke will block by the other thread, so if your UI gets busy through any other means you can still be left with a data loss problem.  Far better to use a queue system in your serial handler, then you can have a background thread that takes the raw data and dispatches it to your UI thread

Comment: I'd recommend using `BeginInvoke`.  If you close the serialport and data comes through the `DataReceived` event, it could lock up.